# PhpStorm perpetual favorites

Tags: phpstorm

In NetBeans, I was able to add a folder to the Favorites window and it would stay there across all projects. This was super helpful for me to quickly access my `.ssh` folder and some other deeply-buried folders in Windows that I often need to get into (like `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc` and `C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra`).

Is there a way to pin those somewhere in PhpStorm so I can always get to them, regardless of what project I have open?

Comment: In PhpStorm (and other IDEA-based IDEs) favorites are project-based only. The only possible alternatives I can think of: 1) custom plugin that adds dedicated button into [FileChooser dialog](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5940?pr=phpStorm); 2) create and use [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) for such tasks (e.g. to open Windows Explorer in that folder). You can keep such commands under one submenu/group.

Comment: Both good solutions. Thanks!

Comment: @LazyOne, I'm looking at that plugin that adds favorites to the "FileChooser dialog," and I can add favorites... but where on earth _is_ the FileChooser dialog? :)

Comment: "File | Open...", "File | Open Directory...", "File | New Project | ..." and many other places -- anywhere where you can call dialog to choose the path the the file or folder. I've just checked it on Windows 7 and it works fine. Maybe other OS uses system native dialog (mainly Mac).. then it would not work there (for obvious reasons).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PhpStorm (and other IDEA-based IDEs) favorites are project-based only.

The only possible alternatives I can think of:

1. [Custom plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/5940?pr=phpStorm) that adds dedicated button into FileChooser dialog (like `File | Open...`, `File | Open Directory...`, `File | New Project | ...` and many other places -- anywhere where you can call dialog to choose the path the the file or folder).

   Here is a screenshot with one Global favorite folder added (called from `File | Open...`)

   [image]
2. Create and use [External Tools](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+External+Tools+in+PhpStorm) for such tasks. The idea here is that you just call Windows Explorer with path of folder to be opened.

   You can keep such commands under one sub menu/group (e.g. "Fav Folders") so they do not mix with other entries.